# When to bet/check with the pot very big?

Tags: nlhe, betting-strategy, cash-game

I played this one on my cellphone so I won't have the perfect hand history but I'll try my best.

NL10 - 6 players
Veeery loose table at 888, with 1 player raising and 3beting almost anything, as I said I was playing on the cellphone so I don't have their stats

SB (Hero) - ~$12
BB - ~$10
UTG (Very Aggro) - ~$8
MP - Empty
CO - $X
BTN - $X

*** Preflop
SB is dealt (Q♥Q♠)

SB posts 0.05
BB posts 0.10
UTG raises 0.35 to 0.45
CO calls 0.45
BTN calls 0.45

SB raises $1.55 to $2
BB calls $1.9
UTG calls $1.9
CO folds
BTN folds

*** Flop ($6.9)
J♦9♣3♦

What would be the best plan here? 
Bet small to induce a shove? Bet big? I don't see much room for maneuver here :/

I have $10 left
BB $8
UTG $6

I have no specific read on BB but I saw UTG 3beting and cold calling a 4bet with T8s OOP among other "unusual" moves

Thanks

Comment: With UTG being aggressive it's tempting to assume he isn't beating you, but BB called two raises out of position. You've only got top pair and you're in worst position. I agree you don't have room to maneuver, and wouldn't it suck of BB made that call with, for example, QKd? Also, since you've seen UTG play T8 before, if he has it this hand you're not looking all that great, particularly if suited to diamonds.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mind about the UTG, but BB could be holding AK, AQ, KQ, TT at least on this level. In this case there are a good amount of awful cards to see in the turn, any A, K, J, T or 9. Would you check fold?

Comment: In general, when I'm SB I'm playing my tightest and I want to see at least 2 pair or a nice draw on the flop to stay in. In this case though, having already made a very large raise pre-flop, you need to determine if a check is going to make you look strong or weak; a strong bet here can easily look like just a continuation, and it sounds like UTG isn't going to fold anyway. I believe I would check, and I would fold to BB but either fold or raise to UTG, depending on the size of the bet. I really like to isolate loose aggressive players but the BB in the pot can spell trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your raise size pre is pretty standard, but given you read on the UTG willing to play anything, I would raise slightly larger.  Flop: shove is standard, any bet is effectively a shove anyways since you cannot bet/fold.  You have a SPR(Stack to pot ratio) of 1.16 to the BB and greater than 1:1 against the UTG.  Checking the flop is just bad.[image]

Comment: What software did you use to generate the above workflow ? I think many would want to know.

Comment: That's CREV, Cardrunners EV. And +1 to his analysis, standard jam.

Comment: Yes, it's CREV.  I couldn't capture the full tree in one snapshot but it's worth mentioning that I set the UTG call range to 60% based on OP's read and the BB call range to 9.5%.

Comment: "any bet is effectively a shove anyways" I agree, in this scenario I was playing for all my chips or giving up the pot. Well, I jammed, BB folded and UTG called me showing JTo.  
What I was wondering is, if I already decided to jam wouldn't it be better to bet small (half the pot or less) to extract more money from the BB? like @Daniel said?  
I know that I'm result oriented sometimes, maybe I'm thinking about this line because the BB folded.

Comment: Betting between 1/2-full pot is standard with a deeper stack size.  When you have a SPR of ~1 there is no point in playing around with smaller bets.  Lets assume you decide to bet small, what size would you bet here?  If you bet too small you are giving cheap drawing cards.  If you bet $3.5(1/2pot) then the UTG only has $2.5 to raise you. Even the worst of players has to assume that they will be called 100% with less then a full raise size.  The other issue you run into is balance.  If you bet small in these situations with value hands and shove with only draws then you can be exploited.

Answer (score 1):

As valentin said -

> A lot of players will say checking is a bad play

So I will try to justify that point :). My plan would be to bet a bit more than 50% on flop and push any turn. Since noone 4 bet preflop on a loose table its safe to assume noone has AA,KK (and probably JJ). This means that there is almost no hand from the tight player you are affraid of (maybe 99) and veeery small percentage of the range of the loose player beats you while at the same time he can go crazy with any jack or draw and you definitely want to go all in on the flop against him.

Another reason you want to raise the flop(besides your will to go all in vs the agro) is the drowy board. If you check there is a chance you give them a free card which is pretty bad with such a vulnerable hand.

Furthermore beting will most likely secure that people with just overcards(without flush draws) will fold so you shouldnt be that scared of A or K on the turn and push. The only reason I would agree to check will be if you know UTG will bet so you can push.

So to sum it up - on this flop you crush their ranges so you should just go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Concidering this is a very loose table, it's hard to tell what to do.

You could try to shut them down on the flop and bet very high so they fold and scoop a nice pot as it is on the flop.

However, sometimes in this position I choose to check the flop because with a lot of draws out there I would just know that they would call and that would be wasted money.
If then on the turn a blank falls, I would bet pretty high so they can't call. If however the turn is a card which makes possible draws complete, I would be careful. Position helps a lot here!!

In your specific example, I would have checked it. A lot of players will say checking is a bad play but I disagree when you play on low stakes like that and the villains are really really loose since the bet would be wasted money if they call the flop 100% of the times... Better keep dem chips for the turn and river! :)

Answer (score -1):

So we are SB and we are repping a strong draw hand possibly 2x high diamonds, or K,Q,J high Str8, holding K10, KQ or J10 or 108.  I think a typical play hear as mentioned above would be to shove with trips and hope to catch a call by UTG or BB missing a similar draw hand. I guess we can assume Trips are likely but not entirely out the range of BB and UTG. UTG could potentially be holding mid pair or made pair but unlikely Trips.

If we assume SB is taking the semi bluff line with a not made hand, but on a draw such as a straight or a flush, SB should hold off and check turn to see how other players bet after the turn to make your decision accordingly. I think a small bet induces a shove/call for sure from either of these players. If not a diamond or connecting card I would Shove post turn 100% of the time. You hope to take the pot down right there, but if you do get called you still have a chance to win the hand if the next cards improve your hand. But if you get re-raised after the turn with a connecting card be prepared to let the hand go, unless you are receiving correct pot odds to call.

Read more here at my [secrets to folding bet ranges](http://www.juswinners.com/poker/secrets-to-folding-ranges/)